# UIMenuController willHideMenu notification not sent if moved, then dismissed with background tap

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotificationcenter, uitapgesturerecognizer, uimenucontroller

I have a fairly simple subclass of UILabel to allow a tap to show a UIMenuController so the text can be copied.  This all works fine in most circumstances.

```
#import "EPHighlightLabel.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface EPHighlightLabel()

@property (unsafe_unretained) bool hasMenuController;

@end

@implementation EPHighlightLabel

- (id)init {
    if ( (self = [super init]) ) {
        self.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(willHideMenu)
                                                 name:UIMenuControllerWillHideMenuNotification
                                               object:nil];

    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(wasTapped:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if(action == @selector(copy:)) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
    }
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder {
    if ([super resignFirstResponder]) {
        self.hasMenuController = false;
        self.highlighted = NO;
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}


- (void)copy:(id)sender {
    UIPasteboard *board = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    [board setString:self.text];
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)willHideMenu {
    if (self.hasMenuController) {
        [self resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

- (IBAction)wasTapped:(id)sender {
    if([self isFirstResponder]) {
        self.hasMenuController = false;
        UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        [menu setMenuVisible:NO animated:YES];
        [menu update];
        [self resignFirstResponder];
    }
    else if([self becomeFirstResponder]) {
        self.hasMenuController = true;
        UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        [menu setMenuVisible:NO animated:YES];
        [menu setTargetRect:self.bounds inView:self];
        [menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
        self.highlighted = YES;
    }
}

@end
```

In the view, there are three of these `EPHighlightLabel` in a UIView that is itself a subview.  Everything works fine, you can tap a label, the text will highlight, then tap again or tap away and the menu will be dismissed and the label unhighlighted.  This is achieved via the `- (void)willHideMenu` call.  However in the following situation the UIMenuControllerWillHideMenu notification is not sent:

1. Tap any label.
2. Label highlighted, menu displayed.
3. Tap any other label.
4. Previous label unhighlighted, new label highlighted and menu displayed/moved.
5. Tap anywhere outside of the labels.  The menu is removed but NO notifications are sent.  Neither UIMenuControllerWillHideMenu or UIMenuControllerDidHideMenu.

Any advice?